# jQuery's trim() prepended with not operator

Tags: javascript, jquery

I came across this conditional statement and I'd like to know the point of it:

```
if(isNaN($(this).val()) || !$.trim($(this).val()))
```

I get if the value is not a number, that makes sense for this function. What doesn't make sense is the `!$.trim()`. If we want to remove the whitespace around our value it makes more sense to write the function like this:

```
if(isNan( $.trim( $(this).val() ) ))
```

Here we trim the value before we calculate `isNan`. What is the purpose of negating the return value of `$.trim()`?

Comment: hint: `!""` returns `true`

Comment: @BeNdErR Correct, but `$.trim("")` returns a string.

Comment: yes, it returns an **empty** string. therefore `!$.trim("")` returns `true`

Comment: Well, `isNaN` is a... ["special" function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN#Confusing_special-case_behavior). As for the trimming, [read the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/). [This table](https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/) would also be useful here. The code is somewhat verbosely written, I'll give you that, but if you know what is happening it is quite understandable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.fn.trim` as you know, will remove leading and trailing white spaces. The `!` operator is checking if, after trimming, the string is empty.

```
!"" == true
```

as an empty string evaluates to `false` in javascript and `!` flips it to `true`